# Unity decompilation UnityEngine.UI referenced but no class in UnityEngine.UI found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reverse-engineering, decompiling, recompile

I have created a small unity game (**about 10 classes**).
Then I have decompiled it with dnSpy. Fixed a few issues and created a VS Project.

My problem is that **Assembly-CSharp.dll** references some unity dlls. But curiosly everithing workes except **UnityEngine.UI**. If I reference **UnityEngine.UI**, the IntelliSence says everything is ok, but if I compile it, all classes in **UnityEngine.UI** where not found.

Comment: Why would you decompile your own game when you should have the source?

Comment: Just for learning more about .net decompilation. I want to decompile some bigger projects later.